# rspec testing that api call increments a counter

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a test that works right now but it's ugly and I can't help thinking there is a better way to do this. Basically I pick a record from the database and then make an api call which should affect that record. However the only way to make the test pass is to pull the record from the database a second time.

```
it "counts how many times a client has pulled its config" do
    client = Endpoint.last
    config_count = client.config_count
    post '/api/config', node_key: client.node_key
    same_client = Endpoint.find_by node_key: client.node_key
    # expect(client.config_count).to eq(config_count + 1)
    expect(same_client.config_count).to eq(config_count + 1)
  end
```

The commented out line does not work. This fix is so ugly that it makes me think I'm doing it wrong. I also tried this:

```
expect {post '/api/config', node_key: client.node_key}.to change {client.config_count}.by(1)
```

So what is the proper way to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably several ways to solve it. I tend to call `.reload` on my object if I want updated values for it and don't care what exactly is happening inside the object itself.

```
it "counts how many times a client has pulled its config" do
  client = Endpoint.last
  config_count = client.config_count
  post '/api/config', node_key: client.node_key
  client.reload
  expect(client.config_count).to eq(config_count + 1)
end
```